# Java: How to pass authority/role to FeintClient?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have the following controller in one of my services:

SomeService

```
public class ExternalController {
  @Autowired private ExternalService externalService;
public static final String USER = "USER";
  @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('" + USER + "')")
  @GetMapping(value = "/{id}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public Data getPlayerPubData(@PathVariable String id){
    return externalService.getData(id);
  }
}
```

I am trying to access this service's api from another api via the following:
AnotherService

```
@FeignClient(
    name = "external-service-integration",
    url = "${external.service.url}")
public interface ExternalServiceIntegration {

  @GetMapping(
      path = "/{id}",
      consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> getGameStatus( // how to pass role here?
      @PathVariable String id);
}
```

However I am getting a `FeignException$Forbidden: [403]` because I am not passing in the user USER credential/authority. How can I achieve this properly?